# Can I create new UI elements and use them from Unity?

Tags: unity, gui

I created the following class, that should be used to display numeric text in a UI canvas (score, lives, etc.):

```
public class NumericField: UnityEngine.UI.Text {
    [SerializeField] int value = 0;

    override protected void Start() {
        base.Start();
        text = value.ToString();
    }

    public int Get() {
        return value;
    }

    public void Set(int newValue) {
        value = newValue;
        text = value.ToString();
    }

    public void Add(int toAdd) {
        Set(value + toAdd);
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to add a NumericField into my Canvas, instead of adding a Text. But, when I right-click the Canvas object, I do not see my NumericField. How can I add it to the menus, so that I can add it to the canvas?

Comment: Have you tried using the ```[CreateAssetMenu]``` attribute?

Comment: Have you tried the usual AddComponent approach? The options you see in the context menu are just shortcuts to create GameObjects with certain commonly-used components, but they're by no means a limit on what components you can use.

Comment: I am not sure if it is even possible to create custom UI components like that. I would usually solve this problem with a MonoBehaviour which implements the API functionality I want by interacting with the UnityEngine.UI.Text component on the same GameObject.

Comment: I would second Philipp's recommendation to implement this numeric field using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). But I can confirm that it is possible to derive your own custom Text classes from the built-in Unity version - [I've used it to support inline icon display](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/680477412287578112), for example.

Comment: @ArturTrapp I added before the class `[CreateAssetMenu(menuName ="NumericField")]`, but it had no effect.

Comment: @DMGregory yes, my previous solution was to make NumericField inherit MonoBehavior, then create Text objects and add to each of them a NumericField. I just thought it would be more convenient to do it in one step than in two steps.